# OpenCV Detecting Scoreboard

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV and I'm trying to figure out a way to detect the presence of a scoreboard from a Soccer video.

i have multiple videos from different sport channels and leagues i.e different score-box formats. The job must reliably detect the scoreboard from different types of scoreboard-formats

My Aim:

of a given image:

1) Detect the scoreboard & location of the scoreboard

2) Draw bounding-box around the scoreboard

[Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbYFJ.jpg)

(My objective is to determine If and When a soccer match has ended in a video - the disappearance of the scoreboard is one of the signs the game has ended - if there are more effecient ways of programmatically detecting the end of a football match automatically in a video outside of my above stated objective I would be interested to know).

Code for this would be much appreciated